# Publish & Update over SFTP with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, deployment, sftp

I'm currently searching for a way to make it possible to deploy and update a C# .NET application over SFTP. Background is that most of my users do not have admin rights, internet access rights or common file structures/group policies. The best I could actually get was the ability to also use the SFTP-infrastructure the application already uses for data transfers.

So I tried using Visual Studio publish, which can deploy the application initially, however it does not support the update mechanisms (it only supports URLs and File Paths). A manual update/deployment process is out of the question, however, purely through the sheer size of the userbase (1000+ users).

I then had a look at *wyBuild*, a third-party build-tool that can actually use sftp to upload Updates. It can not, however, download them via sftp.

So I'm reaching somewhat the end of my rope here. Writing an updater myself seems like a large time investment, but I could not find any other solution. How would this problem be solvable? Thanks for any help in advance.

Oh, and before somebody flags for "asking for a tutorial", I tried hard to stay within the guidelines stackoverflow provides [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question)

Comment: Have you tried using 3rd party tools like [SFTP Net Drive](https://www.eldos.com/sftp-net-drive/) or [WebDrive](http://www.webdrive.com/products/webdrive/)?

Comment: They require Admin rights to install so even if I could get the user to install them (or deploy them along with my application) I sadly can't run them.

Comment: If you consider writing your own updater, check the [WinSCP .NET Assembly](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library). It should help you with accessing SFTP from your own application.

Comment: Yeah, the SFTP-Code is already written, I was just hoping to get around writing my own updater.